# How to convert primitive value to Date object in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I previously convert a date object to primitive value by google app script using `new Date().valueOf()`.

The primitive value is 1.626139723E12.

I would like to convert back primitive value to human readable date object.

I tried:
B4 => 1.626139723E12

B4.Gettime => undefined

B4.toString => 1.626139723E12

new Date(B4) => Invalid Date

B4.toLocaleString() => 1.626139723E12

B4.toUTCString() => is not a function

Utilities.formatDate(B4, "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm:ss") => Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate

Following the comment from Copper, I also try:

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var PropName = "Last time"
var LastForwardTime = scriptProperties.getProperty(PropName); 

function test(){
  Logger.log(LastForwardTime);
  const dt = new Date(LastForwardTime);
  Logger.log(dt)
}
```

The log is as follows:

```
1:38:09 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:38:11 PM  Info    1.626139723E12
1:38:11 PM  Info    Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 GMT+08:00 1970
1:38:09 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

It is not working properly.

So is there a way can convert primitive value back to Date object in google app script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Date constructor `const dt = new Date(value);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the full GAS code using your method in my question. It seems the method is not working properly.

Comment: I think I found the answer by modifying your answer as const dt = new Date(parseFloat(value)); Thank you.=3=